# Generate event handler without jumping to code in VS2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am working on WPF application. Whenever I want to add an event handler by double clicking near event's name in Properties window I am immediately transfered to generated code. I don't want this behaviour, I simply want to generate empty methods fast and get them added to XAML file and then jump into code. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, it is impossible to do that. The behavior is that you double click and are in fact thrown to the code behind because the logical thing to do is to start adding code in the body of the event handler. This behavior is fine for 99% of the developers out there.

Comment: Ok then. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The behavior is expected for 99% of the circumstances, but sometimes it would really be helpful if a key press (e.g. Ctrl or Shift) can suppress this.